# getStaticProps returns data not defined In nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to fetch single data by id and I am using `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` but I am getting the error data is not defined. Where am I going wrong Please help

My `[id].tsx` file

```
import MainComponentLayout from "../../components/Layout/MainLayoutComponent"
import EditProject from "../../components/EditProjectForm";

// HOW MANY HTML PAGES NEEDS TO BE MADE BASED ON OUR DATA
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://b560-45-248-23-129.ngrok.io/projects`)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    const path = data.result.map(project => {
        return{
            params: {id:project.project_ID}
        }
    })
    return{
        paths:path,
        fallback: false
    }
}
// FETCH SINGLE DATA
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const id = context.params.id
    const response = await fetch(`http://b560-45-248-23-129.ngrok.io/projects/${id}`)
    // Single Object
    const data = await response.json()
    return{
        props: {fetchedData:data},
    }
}

const EditForm = () => {
    return(
        <MainComponentLayout ComponentToRender = {<EditProject fetchedData = {fetchedData}/>}/>
    )
}


export default EditForm
```

Comment: You haven't defined `fetchedData` .. maybe you want to? Like extract it from props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to use `props` `{fetchedData:data}` in your app, You need pass them to the `page component` as `props`. As we can read in [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching):

> props - An optional object with the props that will be received by the
> page component. It should be a serializable object

Here You have [example](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) page with `getStaticProps()` correctly used.

---

and Your code with props, Good Luck ! ;-)

```
import MainComponentLayout from "../../components/Layout/MainLayoutComponent";
import EditProject from "../../components/EditProjectForm";

const EditForm = ({ fetchedData }) => {
  return (
    <MainComponentLayout
      ComponentToRender={<EditProject fetchedData={fetchedData} />}
    />
  );
};

// FETCH SINGLE DATA
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://b560-45-248-23-129.ngrok.io/projects/${id}`
  );
  // Single Object
  const data = await response.json();
  return {
    props: { fetchedData: data },
  };
};

// HOW MANY HTML PAGES NEEDS TO BE MADE BASED ON OUR DATA
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`http://b560-45-248-23-129.ngrok.io/projects`);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  const path = data.result.map((project) => {
    return {
      params: { id: project.project_ID },
    };
  });
  return {
    paths: path,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export default EditForm;
```

Comment: When I console the fetchedData prop in EditProject component I get undefined Why is it so ?

Comment: @Sachin check url in  fetch function...

Answer (score 1):

Change `const EditForm = () => {` to `const EditForm = ({fetchedData}) =>`  and it will work.

The `getStaticProps`, as its name implies, passes the fetched props object to the function as properties. You need to define them in the function as an object, and you can also destructure as in the example above, basically defining a `fetchedData` variable.